# How to easily transfer qpython scripts from windows to android for development?

Tags: qpython

while developing qpython scripts, it would be much easier to develop them on a pc and only transfer them to the android device for testing.

What is the easiest way to do such a transfer? (Development might require to do this very frequently)

Thanks in advance for all your feedback.

tfv

Answer (score 1):

In linux with ADB installed, in terminal you can use

`adb push pcprojectfolder /sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/projects/androidprojectfolder`

You do need to manually end the task on the phone before pushing though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ftp service in setting part which can help you to translate files between android device and pc.

Answer (score 0):

QPy for android has built in FTP. Just enter the local address it provides into an ftp program (like bareftp for ubuntu)